# How to convert the boolean value to yes or no in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a boolean variable which is binding using this element in KnockoutJS:

> ```
> <span data-bind="text: myBooleanVar"></span>
> ```

I want to show yes or no in the UI instead of true or false. I tried different functions to convert the value to yes or no but they did not work. 
I think there should be a simple way to do this. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below lines of code - by using conditional operator.

```
<span data-bind="text: myBooleanVar? 'Yes' : 'No'"></span>
```

Comment: including logic in your view is kind of a no-no. It really should be pushed back into the viewmodel as either a helper function or a knockout computed

Comment: If myBooleanVar is an observable this won't work unless you unwrap it.

Answer (score 5):

You could put the logic in the view (@Ravi Dasari's answer) or put it in the view model (@dperry's answer) but I think a custom binding would also be an applicable approach.

```
<span data-bind="boolean: myBooleanVar"></span> <!-- (Defaults to "Yes" or "No")-->
<span data-bind="boolean: myBooleanVar, trueText: 'Absolutely', falseText: 'Negative'"></span>


ko.bindingHandlers.boolean = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var bool = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            trueText = allBindings.get('trueText') || 'Yes',
            falseText = allBindings.get('falseText') || 'No';
        $(element).text(bool ? trueText : falseText);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ravi's answer works, but including logic like that in your view isn't best practice. You could either create a knockout computed function or a helper function:

```
var viewmodel = function() {
    var self = this;

    // the actual value (not attached to self to keep it private)
    var myBooleanVar = ko.observable(true);

    // wrapped version for the UI
    self.myBooleanUI = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.myBooleanVar() ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    });
}
```

The view:

```
<span data-bind="text: myBooleanUI"></span>
```